# Android: Null Exception error for retrieving value from snapshop to textview

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am creating a feedback app where the user rates a service from 1-5 and I display the average of all the user's ratings (till date) on the next page. The average rating is coming out to be fine but I am not able to fetch the total number of users from snapshot that have rated on the app till now.

Here is the code -

```
public class Score extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView avgScore;
    TextView totalUsers;
    double userCount;
    DatabaseReference dbRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.score);
        avgScore = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        scoreRealTime();
    }

    public void scoreRealTime() {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                double total = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserHelper helper = ds.getValue(UserHelper.class);
                    double values = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(helper.rating));
//                  double values = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("rating").getValue().toString());
                    total = total + values;
                    userCount = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                }
                double average = (double) total / snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                avgScore.setText(String.format("%.2f", average));
                //System.out.println(userCount);
                totalUsers.setText((int) userCount); //error occurs here
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error log -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.feedback, PID: 26338
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.feedback.Score$1.onDataChange(Score.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

EDIT: Also, it would be really great if you could explain why the NullPointerException is occurring here or occurs in general. Thanks.

Comment: From the code, it results that you didn't initialized your `totalUsers` TextView. The `NullPointerException` happens because you declared `totalUsers` globally, which initializes it to null by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not link totalUsers. You need to do

```
totalUsers = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

as well